# Error "HTTP 401 Invalid credential" on dev site (Basic HTTP Auth issue)

Tags: untagged

After resyncing the database from live to dev I hit the above error on any CiviCRM paths.

Answer (score 3):

From  https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22837

In case future me or someone else hits this again hopefully this will provide a solution.

On dev site which is **behind basic http auth** you can run:

cv vset authx_header_cred=[]

If you are hitting this error not on a dev site / behind Basic Http Auth then you probably have a different problem.